# Webview causes infinite scrollable white space

Tags: android, webview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a layout which contained Webview inside NestedScrollview,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.app.swipetofinish.SwipeDownLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/postContainer"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/postDetails"
        android:background="?attr/backgroundColor">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:id="@+id/postFeaturedImage"/>

            <com.app.customizeviews.Lato_Bold_TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"
                android:letterSpacing="0.02"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/postTitle"
                android:layout_below="@+id/postFeaturedImage"/>

            <com.app.customizeviews.Lato_Regular_TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/postDate"
                android:textColor="?attr/secondaryTextColor"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/postTitle"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/postDate"
                android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>

            <ProgressBar
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="50dp"
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        </RelativeLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/postDetails"
        android:elevation="25dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bottom_post_card">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_ext_link_enabled"
            android:id="@+id/sourceLink"
            android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_share_dark_article"
            android:id="@+id/postShare"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/sourceLink"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/postLike"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_like_article_unselected"
            android:id="@+id/postLike"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/postBookmark"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/postShare"/>

        <TextSwitcher
            android:id="@+id/likesCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/postBookmark"
            android:clipToPadding="false"
            android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_up"
            android:outAnimation="@anim/fade_out"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/postLike"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/postLike"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/postLike" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_bookmark_article_unselected"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:id="@+id/postBookmark"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

and this working perfectly, but from last day it start causing infinite blank space after the web content ends, like this

[image]

All the white blank space is caused by Webview after the main contents of Webview.This happens only when I open this layout in a fragment with ViewPager but not if layout open in layout with a single page activity.
And also this working perfectly until yesterday from 2-3 months but from yesterday I'm getting this issue.

Code for loading contents in Webview :

```
mWebView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
        mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
        }
        mWebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            mWebView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        } else {
            mParentView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        }
 mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
                            "file:///android_asset/",
                            content,
                            "text/html",
                            "utf-8",
                            null);
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `wrap_content` to `RelativeLayout` height attribute inside `NestedScrollView` like below code

```
  <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/postDetails"
    android:background="?attr/backgroundColor">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"> //change here

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:id="@+id/postFeaturedImage"/>

        <com.app.customizeviews.Lato_Bold_TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="?attr/primaryTextColor"
            android:letterSpacing="0.02"
            android:lineSpacingExtra="6sp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:id="@+id/postTitle"
            android:layout_below="@+id/postFeaturedImage"/>

        <com.app.customizeviews.Lato_Regular_TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/postDate"
            android:textColor="?attr/secondaryTextColor"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/postTitle"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp" />

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/postDate"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/progressBar"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```